# Remover caracteres especiais e espaços de uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho um problema, em um app estou pegando os contatos da agenda telefônica, porém quero fazer um tratamento nos números dos contatos que podem vir assim:

```
(99) 9999-9999
9999-9999
9999 9999
```

e entre outras coisas, o único tratamento que fiz foi usar um `SubString` para cortar e pegar apenas os últimos 8 caracteres do número (para tirar operadora etc), agora como faço para remover caracteres que não sejam números dessas *string*? No exemplo acima todos os números ficariam assim: `99999999`

Comment: Só para deixar anotado, existem números de 9 dígitos também, em algumas regiões. Logo, pegar os últimos 8 caracteres pode não ser a melhor opção dependendo do uso de seu app.

Comment: Aqui peguei os 8 dígitos pois o app é para Windows Phone (que não possui nenhuma ferramenta que coloca 9 digito) e estou tratando isso depois.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alguém vai dar uma solução com RegEx, mas eu prefiro assim, utilizando método de extensão:

```
var texto = "(99) 9999-9999";
foreach (var chr in new string[] {"(", ")", "-", " " }) {
    texo = texto.Replace(chr, "");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iIUJBe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u42s38). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Replace.cs).

Obviamente se quiser guardar isto na variável precisa armazenar de novo o resultado do método na variável.

Dá para fazer de forma mais otimizada. Exemplo:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static string Replace(this string str, string newValue, params char[] chars) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var chr in str) {
            if (!chars.Contains(chr)) {
                sb.Append(chr);
            } else {
                sb.Append(newValue);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cXbUqk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dl3rEX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BetterReplace.cs).

Comment: O que quer dizer com otimizada? Usa menos recurso de memória? ou o que ?

Comment: Memória e processamento.

Answer (score 5):

Como foi previsto pelo @Maniero, vou mostrar o método utilizando [Regex.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) substituindo tudo em uma só linha, fique a vontade para escolher como deseja trabalhar:

```
string strTexto = "(12) 3456-7890";
strTexto = Regex.Replace(strTexto, "[\\(\\)\\-\\ ]", "");
Console.WriteLine(strTexto);
```

Rodando no .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cid0m